# How to check for null before I use in linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an list of objects that contains another object in it.

```
List<MyClass> myClass = new List<MyClass>();
```

I want to do some linq like this

```
myClass.Where(x => x.MyOtherObject.Name = "Name").ToList();
```

Thing is sometimes "MyOtherObject" is null. How do I check for this?

Comment: do you mean `== "Name"`?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Simple, just add an `AND` clause to check if it's not null:

```
myClass.Where(x => x.MyOtherObject != null && x.MyOtherObject.Name = "Name").ToList();
```

Answer (score 10):

As of C# 6, you can also use a [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) `?.`:

```
myClass.Where(x => x.MyOtherObject?.Name == "Name").ToList();
```

This will essentially resolve the `Name` property to null if `MyOtherObject` is null, which will fail the comparison with `"Name"`.

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/07VBFT)

Answer (score 3):

You can just make your predicate check for null...

```
myClass.Where(x => (x.MyOtherObject == null) ? false : x.MyOtherObject.Name == "Name").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
myClass.Where(x => x.MyOtherObject != null)
       .Where(y => y.MyOtherObject.Name = "Name")
       .ToList();
```